# Problem on non abelian tensor product of groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, tensor-products, infinite-groups

Let $G$ be group and $x\otimes[y,z] =([x,y]\otimes z)^2$, for any $x,y,z\in G$. Then prove
$$[x,y]\otimes y=1_{\otimes},$$ for any $x,y\in G$.

This is a part of Corollary 4 in page 82 in the article of P. Moravec, *On nonabelian tensor analogues of 2-Engel condition*, Glasgow Math. J. 47 (2005) 77-86.

Thank you

Comment: By $[x,y]$ do you mean $x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$?

Comment: I wonder what can possibly mean $\,1_\otimes\;$ here...?

Comment: Ok. $[x,y]=x^{-1}y^{-1}xy$  and  $1_{\otimes}$ is identity element of group $G\otimes G$.